# Turring Machine Variant and Equivalent Traditional

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques

Turing Machine where instead of having a set of final
states F it has:
A designated final state qaccept which exists in Q set of states. Upon being in this state, it halts, and accepts
the input.
A designated reject state qreject which exists in Q set of states. Upon being in this state, it halts, but rejects
the input.
Also: If the TM is not in the accept or reject state, it does not halt
This sounds like a half and half combo of a decider and transducer, and I don't know how to start the proof in either direction i.e. constructing a standard TM from a variant and also a variant from a standard. How would I prove equivalency from either direction?

Comment: Please don't re-post your question when it is closed: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163281/755.  Instead, edit the original post to address the feedback.  Please address all of the feedback provided.